# Prepare to presentation (sentences)

Tags: phrase-usage

I have to be presenter of teamwork done for American owner.
I haven't done it yet.

I would like prepare several sentences for correct to use.

1. Have all joined? Have all saw my screen ?
2. You can see - *I many times use it. Maybe, are the alternatives?*
3. Here it looks like - *And I will show how something to work*
4. Is it look for you well ?

p.s maybe you know other general sentences ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my suggestions:

1) **Has everyone joined? Can you all see my screen?**

2) **As you can see...**

3) **And here we have...** (or, **Let me demonstrate**, or, **Let me show you how this works...**)

4) **Can you see this okay?** (or, **Does everything look okay at your end?**)

---

Lastly, there's nothing wrong with an early disclaimer:

- *Sorry if I struggle a little with my English*.

Hopefully, your audience will be understanding if you have a few grammar problems.

Good luck in your presentation!

Comment: Possible alternate interpretation of #4:  *Does that look good to you?* or *Do you like how it looks?*